# optimize code ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do this in my edit functions , update, destroy

```
@post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
if @post.user_id == current_user.id
```

there any way to optimize and make a single function, you used to like this:

```
before_action :set_user_post, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

private
def set_user_post
  @post = current_user.posts.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

But add the friendly_id gem and modify it as follows:

```
private
def set_user_post
  @post = current_user.posts.friendly.find(id: params[:id])
end
```

But it gives me error.
error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'id.id' in 'where clause': SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = 1 AND `id`.`id` = 'primero' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please post the error message including the filename and line number and the full stack trace.

Comment: Error: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'id.id' in 'where clause': SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = 1 AND `id`.`id` = 'primero' LIMIT 1 @spickermann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find` method finds a record by id and you can only pass a single id or an array of ids as input. But in your method, you're passing a hash. Modify your `set_user_post` method as

```
def set_user_post
  begin
    @post = current_user.posts.friendly.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to root_path, alert: 'You are knocking at the wrong door'
  end
end
```

If a user's trying to access another user's post, the `find` method will raise an exception cause we're finding the posts of the `current_user`. We can rescue the exception and redirect the user to the home page with a
warning flash message.

**EXTRA**

You can also find a record using `find_by`method and pass it a hash. This method is used to find a record with any field(not just id). It returns the first record which matches the query.

For example,

```
def set_user_post
  @post = current_user.posts.friendly.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

This does the same thing but the difference is that `find` raises an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception if a record doesn't exist with the given id while `find_by` returns `nil` if a record doesn't exist.

For more, see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find

Comment: thanks , it works, but if not the creator of the post , as redirected , so that this message does not appear me: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound @Arun Kumar

Comment: @CarlosUrielPatiñoSantiago I don't understand you. Can you explain a bit more clearly? Are you getting an error or is any user able to edit another's post?

Comment: ok , example :
I believe this question only I can edit , but if another user wants to edit and put in the url: question / edit , shows this errror :ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound , but I want to redirect the beginning , as I do apologize for any inconvenience just start and I have many doubts , @Aurun Kumar

Comment: @CarlosUrielPatiñoSantiago Updated.

Comment: hank you very much! @Arun Kumar